# Rails scope with raw SQL throws syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a scope on one of my models where I use raw SQL (Postgres). It looks like this:

```
scope :with_rating, lambda {
  select <<~SQL
    sellers.*, ROUND(SUM(average_score * total_reviews) / SUM(total_reviews)) AS seller_rating, SUM(total_reviews) AS total_reviews
      FROM (
        SELECT
          (products.meta -> 'yotpo_bottom_line' ->> 'average_score')::numeric AS average_score,
          (products.meta -> 'yotpo_bottom_line' ->> 'total_reviews')::numeric AS total_reviews,
          sellers.*
        FROM sellers
      INNER JOIN products ON products.seller_id = sellers.id
    ) t JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = t.id
    GROUP BY sellers.id
  SQL
}
```

However, when I try to use it, after the `GROUP BY` Rails adds another line:

```
FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "sellers"."id" = 1063 LIMIT 1;
```

Which throws:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 11: FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "sel...
         ^
```

Comment: (1) Why is that a scope? Looks more like a complete query than a building block for queries to me. (2) The `"sellers"."deleted_at" IS NULL`  looks like a default scope related to soft-deletes but where are the 1063 and LIMIT coming from? How do you use this "scope"?

Comment: @muistooshort I want postgres to do some calculations and return either a single record (as in this example) or a set of records with `seller_rating` present as an attribute. Is there a best practice i'm missing?

Comment: The problem is that you're feeding a complete query to `#select` when you should be doing `select(...).joins(...)...` in the scope so that you can throw a `.where(sellers: { id: 1063 })` on it or leave it as-is.

Comment: Any chance you can point me in the right direction as to how to do so? I'm confused since it involves a subquery